# how to host multiple pages from diferent domains all together?

Tags: redirection, url, cname

I create landing pages in order to launch PPC campaigns for my customers. However, I would like to host them all together under a sub-domain of MY website.
  For example:
 I want that someone who visits **www.clientnumber2.com/landingpage** could see the landing page and still the same URL **www.clientnumber2.com/landingpage**, but actually host it myself.

The same for client3, client4, and so on...

Comment: Is it possible that there has been a typo and you meant ´clientnumber1.com´ and ´clientnumber2.com´? If that is the case, you might want to look into namebased hosts, which e.g. Apache makes available [via SNI](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI). You would simply configure the A-Record of all Domains to the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this would be to host your landing page on a separate subdomain, something like `www2.clientnumber2.com` and then the client could setup the DNS record to point at your server.

Otherwise, if you want your landing page to be a subdirectory of the main site your client's servers would most likely have to proxy the request.

Comment: Indeed the answer is subdomain, and it's more elegant.

Comment: can i create a subdomain for landings like landings.mywebsite.com so then every new customer only has to point to it ? (keeping the rest of their website working)

Comment: Yes, but I thought the point was to keep the URL on the client's domain.  Was that not the case?

Comment: yes, thats the point. Visitors should still see the same URL... i was thinking about something related to CNAME ?

Comment: Sure, your client could setup a CNAME record to point a subdomain, like `landing.clientsite.com` to your server (`landings.mywebsite.com`).  However, if you don't want the domain to change at all (meaning you must have `www.clientsite.com/landingpage`) then the client's server will need to proxy the request.